# How to cast NSNumber to long long int correctly?

Tags: ios, int, nsnumber

im trying to cast NSNumber to long long int but I'm getting unexpected values.. What am I doing wrong?

```
NSNumber *number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:60];
if ([self isTimeOver:number]) {
    [self sendPushTest];
}

-(BOOL)isTimeOver: (NSNumber*) interval {
    long long int theInterval = (long long int)interval;
    NSLog(@"THE INTERVAL %lld",theInterval); // I get -5764607523034233918 here.
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `-longLongValue` since `long long int` and `long long` are the same.

```
long long int theInterval = [interval longLongValue];
```

You should never try just casting `NSNumber`s to primitive types (doing so will result in the garbage number you got). Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.

Comment: Yup. To expand a bit: `NSNumber` is not a primitive value like `int`, but an object that contains a value. Thus, you can't use casting to get the value—instead you call methods on the object to get the value.